# How to make POST request using Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, retrofit

This may be a silly question, but I'm new to developing Android applications.

I need to receive some data from API by using Retrofit 2.0. I found several tutorials on the internet, furthermore, I even got a list of Github repositories, but... 
none seems to provide any concrete information.

For example, I want to send E-Mail and password to the /login method, and then this method needs to return an authentication token. But I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! No question is silly until you tried something, Just try to look a bit professional and I am sure someone will help you out. Also show what have you tried till now or what exactly your problem is. The question you asked is a bit too broad.

Comment: @KashyapKotak Thanks for your friendliness! If briefly, the essence of the question is how to make a POST-query to the API's method with e-mail and password as parameters, and how to receive one of the values which this method returns. Also it is important to note that parameters should be sent in JSON, and returned by the API data also should be received in JSON. Please, give me some articles or tutorials I ought to check, if you can :)

Comment: https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-2-authorization-handling-ea1431cb86be this tutorial guides you through the whole process or authorization, for example, on retrofit with concrete code examples

Comment: @akseli Thank you very much, I will definitely try this! How to say "thanks" on this website? :)